# Error 400 when trying to upload a file to Sharepoint using Python and REST API

Tags: python, rest, api, sharepoint, upload

I am trying to write a python script that can access a sharepoint and upload excel files to it. I have managed to get to the point where I pass authentication and retrieve the FormDigestValue, but I can't seem to get the upload command right. Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

#get formdigestvalue
headers = {'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'}
r = requests.post("https://sharepoint.example.com/example/_api/contextinfo",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('username', 'password'), headers=headers)
print r.status_code
FormDigestValue = r.json()['d']['GetContextWebInformation']['FormDigestValue']
print FormDigestValue

#file upload
POSTheaders = {'Accept':'application/json; odata=verbose','Content-Type':'application/json; odata=verbose',
               'X-RequestDigest':FormDigestValue, 'binaryStringRequestBody':'true'}

posturl = "https://sharepoint.example.com/example/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Trainings/Training Records/JohnSmith')/files/add(url=""test.xlsx"", overwrite='true')"

excelfile = {'file': ('test.xlsx', open('test.xlsx', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')}

auth=HttpNtlmAuth('username', 'password')

p = requests.post(posturl, headers=POSTheaders, files = excelfile, auth = auth)

print p.status_code
print p.content
```

The output I get from this is the following:

```
200
0x63B311022FB07B3B7D7751B0B06C2EF0232DDACD9255DF871FD7599E08A2A014B06ED22DE55246C7F0C7459D8717E347631390502ED7556C6019BB69C7745EA0,15 Feb 2017 12:50:17 -0000
400
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The expression \"web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Trainings/Training Records/JohnSmith')/files/add(url=test.xlsx, overwrite='true')\" is not valid."}}}
```

Unfortunately the error message isn't giving too much detail on what's wrong, and no matter how I tweak the post request, I cannot get past it. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need single quotes here `url=test.xlsx`.
The message says that that query is incorrect, or syntax is incorrect to be exact.
Here is a link with examples where single quotes are used.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx

Comment: The problem with single quotes is that Python considers that section a variable then, and I get an error when trying to run the script. Is there a way to make it single quote, but without removing it from the large string that is the post request?

Comment: Does Python supports character escaping? It must be something like this `" \' "`.
Also this is your string right `"https://sharepoint.example.com/example/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Trainings/Training Records/JohnSmith')/files/add(url=""test.xlsx"", overwrite='true')"`

I clearly see you are using single quotes everywhere but here `url=""test.xlsx""`, why cant it be used here? Try using `url='test.xlsx' ` or escape single quotes `url=\'test.xlsx\'`

Comment: That's what it was, works fine with url='test.xlsx'. I don't know how I failed to spot this; thanks a lot for the help.